# What are events and observers in magento

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

I developed a package with the most powerful functionality of `Magento`, Events and Observers. 
But I don't have much knowledge about them. I googled and tried to find any tutorials, but nothing got.

Any one have any tutorials or any documents about them kindly let me know.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=events+and+observers+in+magento yields plenty of results (including one from both danchet and oguz's answers)

Comment: I've written a tutorial on Events and Observers with working code and config files, this will give you an excellent starting point. Its located here -> http://z900collector.wordpress.com/magento/magento-events/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the some links that I have :

- [Event Observers in Magento](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105)
- [Observers and Dispatching Events](http://codemagento.com/2011/04/observers-and-dispatching-events/)
- [Event Observer with Save before and Save after](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/)
- [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)